# Compare 2 SharePoint list items if they match fill label with colour code stored in a 3rd column

Tags: lookup, conditional-formatting, powerapps

I have some hard wired code that allows me to take a list item and if it = "some text" the label fill colour will be (for example) Red

i would like to compare the first SharePoint item to another SharePoint list column item then fill the label with the colour value stored in another column

Long working version

```
If(
!IsBlank(
    LookUp(
        RP_Tasks_SPList, Task_Owner = Label3.Text &&  
        Text(DateValue(Date_of_Task_From), "yyyy-mm-dd") = Text(DateTimeValue(Button2_2.Text), 
"yyyy-mm-dd") &&
        Task_Type_Short = "FLT"
    )
),
Color.DarkRed,
RGBA(241,244,249, 1)
)
```

Code I am trying to get to work

```
If(
!IsBlank(
    LookUp(
        RP_Tasks_SPList, Task_Owner = Label3.Text &&  
        Text(DateValue(Date_of_Task_From), "yyyy-mm-dd") = Text(DateTimeValue(Button2_2.Text), 
"yyyy-mm-dd") &&
        Task_Type_Short = Filter(RP_Faulting_Maintenace_Codes_SPList,FM_Code_Short)
    )
),
LookUp(RP_Faulting_Maintenace_Codes_SPList,FM_Code_Colour),
RGBA(241,244,249, 1)
)
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the job

```
If(
!IsBlank(
    LookUp(
        RP_Tasks_SPList, Task_Owner = Name_Ref_Label.Text && 
Task_Type_Short=Task_Label_Short.Text && 
        Text(DateTimeValue(Date_of_Task_From), "yyyy-mm-dd") = 
Text(DateTimeValue(Date_Ref_Label.Text), "yyyy-mm-dd")
    )
),
LookUp(RP_Tasks_SPList,Task_Type_Short = Task_Label_Short.Text,Task_Type_Long),
```